# Get middle numbers of a list

Tags: haskell

I want to reorder a list in the following way:

```
[5,6,7,8,9] -> [7,5,9,6,8]
[6,7,8,5,4,3] -> [8,5,6,3,7,4]
```

It's supposed to get the middle number or numbers of the list and put them in the starting position. After that it should start to get the two outer numbers of the list and add them in and work its way in.

I have the following code to get the middle numbers and put them into the beginning of the list but can't figure out how to start adding the outer numbers into the new list.

```
-- import Data.List
-- import System.IO

longitude xs = length xs

middle xs = length xs `div` 2

addOne xs = middle xs - 1

oneMore xs = length xs - 1

otherCase xs = oneMore xs `div` 2

valuea xs =  xs !! middle xs

valueb xs = xs !! addOne xs

valuec xs = xs !! otherCase xs

modulus xs = longitude xs `mod` 2

order xs = midNums xs

takes xs = take (otherCase xs) xs

oddOne xs = otherCase xs + 1

takeX xs = drop (oddOne xs) xs

value xs = takes xs ++ takeX xs

reorder xs = drop (otherCase xs )(take (middle xs + 1) xs)

valueOdd xs = reorder xs ++ takes xs ++ takeX xs  

paruno xs = drop (middle xs + 1) xs

pairTwo xs = take (addOne xs) xs

midPair xs = take (addOne xs)(drop (middle xs -1) xs)

--Get the numbers
midNums xs = if modulus xs == 0 then midPair xs ++ paruno xs ++ pairTwo xs
else valueOdd xs
```

I want it to work like this: [Demo](http://rextester.com/EBSFBF27492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f xs = if len `mod` 2 == 1 then flatten [xs !! half] else flatten [xs !! (half-1), xs !! half]
    where len = length xs
          half = len `div` 2
          firsthalf = take (half-1) xs
          secondhalf = (reverse . take half . drop (half+1)) xs
          outtoin = zipWith (\x y -> x:y:[]) firsthalf secondhalf
          flatten = concat . flip (:) outtoin
```

Breaking it down:

- First get the midpoint(s)
- Next get the two halves of the list excluding middle elements
- Build the list from outside inwards using zip
- Concatenate the zip result to flatten and add to the middle elements list

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LRSCR60022)

Comment: Thanks it works, however it doesn't work the way I want it to work. I want the outer numbers of the list after the two middle numbers and start to work their way in. Like this [Demo](http://rextester.com/EBSFBF27492)

Comment: I've updated the code. Was off with my indexing a bit in the `secondhalf` function. You might want to try again